# How to avoid automatic data type transfer from int type to float type when inserting data to Apache IoTDB?

Tags: floating-point, integer, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I have a question on Apache IoTDB. When inserting data in java, for example using `insertRecord` method, and when the data type is `int`, if I tried to insert these data to IoTDB, the data type will automatically become `float` type. Is there any way to avoid this?